# Returning multiple values in a for loop function

Tags: python

The concept of return in a function don't enter my head.

I created this code to generate random passwords, and the return value exits the for loop i created and then just send me one result.

```
import random
import string


def criador_senha(tamanho, quantidade):
    for senha in range(quantidade):
        senha = []
        for char in range(tamanho):
            lower = string.ascii_lowercase
            upper = string.ascii_uppercase
            num = string.digits
            special = string.punctuation
            char = lower + upper + num + special
            senha += str(random.choice(char))
    return print(senha)


quantidade = input("How many passwords? ")
quantidade = int(quantidade)

tamanho = input("What's the lenght? ")
tamanho = int(tamanho)

criador_senha(tamanho, quantidade)
```

How can i fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function does not return anything.  It exists only for its side effects.  Thus, your function returns `None`.

As a VERY general rule, a utility function like this should do its job and return a useful value.  It should be up to the caller to decide what to DO with that value (like print it).

Also, you were reinitializing the `senha` list every time through the outer loop.  I expect you want it to accumulate everything here.

Also, there's no reason to recompute the list of characters in each loop.  It isn't going to change.

Also, you have a bad habit of reusing your variables.  You had `senha` with two meanings, and `char` with two meanings.  That's an easy way to make bugs.

Also, your `random.choice` is going to return a 1-character string.  There's no need to call `str` on something that's already a string.

Finally, you were appending all of the characters into one big list.  I expect you want a list of individual passwords of the given length.

```
import random
import string


def criador_senha(tamanho, quantidade):
    senha = []
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    num = string.digits
    special = string.punctuation
    alphabet = lower + upper + num + special
    for _ in range(quantidade):
        pw = ''
        for char in range(tamanho):
            pw += random.choice(alphabet)
        senha.append(pw)
    return senha

quantidade = input("How many passwords? ")
quantidade = int(quantidade)

tamanho = input("What's the lenght? ")
tamanho = int(tamanho)

print(criador_senha(tamanho, quantidade))
```

Those nested loops can be replaced with one statement:

```
    senha = [''.join( [random.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(tamanho)]) for _ in range(quantidade)]
```

But that's going a bit far for today.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and the tips!